# Azure Web App getting time out of 4 minuets idle

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-web-app-service

I have hosted ASP.NET MVC application in Azure Web APP its getting time-out of 4 Minutes. The session is clearing for that instance.

Now I'm using Free Shared Infrastructure pricing tire, if I changing the plan to extend this idle timeout? or did I missed any configuration to setup session time-out.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Azure (Free F1 WebApp) Session Management](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35408512/azure-free-f1-webapp-session-management)

Answer (score 1):

> Now I'm using Free Shared Infrastructure pricing tire, if I changing the plan to extend this idle timeout? or did I missed any configuration to setup session time-out.

It is no relationship with pricing tire. It is limited by Azure WebApp. For more information, we could refer to [Why does my request time out after 240 seconds?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-availability-performance-application-issues-faq#why-does-my-request-time-out-after-240-seconds)

> Azure Load Balancer has a default idle timeout setting of four minutes. **This is generally a reasonable response time limit for a web request**. If your web app requires background processing, we recommend using Azure WebJobs. The Azure web app can call **WebJobs** and be notified when background processing is finished. You can choose from multiple methods for using WebJobs, including queues and triggers.

Comment: Thank you Tom. I don't have any background process. Is there any other way to increase the idle timeout. Because 4 minutes is very less and by default .NET providing 20 minutes. If the application is getting timeout frequently means it will be annoying to the user.

Comment: If use the Azure WebApp, answer is no. If azure Cloud service or Azure Virtual machine is acceptable, you could  have a try. But I recommand that you could use the [Webjob](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-create-web-jobs) , it is an easy and economy way to do that.

Comment: Tom, I have also seen most of them are recommending WebJob. But currently I don't have any needs to run in background. Can you give some normal example like can we do site health check or, etc...